# What is the difference between Paypal and PaypalUk?

Tags: magento, paypal

I am working with Paypal. And our shop uses PaypalUk instead of Paypal. And I don\’t know why. 
What is the difference between Paypal and PaypalUk?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what specific service your shop is referring to by PayPal as it could be referring to Website Payments Pro, Express Checkout, or Website Payments Standard.  Most likely your shop is referring to PayPalUK as the Payflow integration method.  If you have set up Website Payments Pro you would of used an API user id, password and signature or certificate.  The Payflow integration goes through a different endpoint, the variables are different and you pass over a user, vendor, partner, and password for your credentials.  You should be able to go into the set up page for the different services in your shop and see if they are asking for a user, vendor, partner, and password.

Comment: Thank's for your answer. We have Express Checkout and Payflow Pro Gateway. Express checkout is link to `paypaluk/express/start/` , but if I click the button it won't works. I wil have error message 'PayPal gateway rejected the request. User authentication failed' . I tried to change link to `paypal/express/start/` and it work's! I can't fixe it be my own.

Comment: I would need to look at your Payflow/PayPal account specifically and see how it is set up.  If you could open up a ticket with PayPal Merchant Technical Support at www.paypal.com/mts and provide me with your ticket number, and your details in that ticket I can take a look at your account.